# Миниатюры категорий товара WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

Страница магазина
https://essenti.com.ua/

Вставил шорткод
`[product_categories orderby="menu_order" columns=4]`

На десктопе показывает правильно. Но на мобильном картинки генерируются в меньшем, чем надо, размере.

Есть ещё два сайта с теми же, по-моему, настройками, но там всё показывает правильно. Не могу понять, в чём ошибка.

Помогите.

Comment: мы тоже так не поймём в чём ошибка, приведите пример кода который у вас используется для генерации

Comment: Я не буду менять код. Я на 99 процентов уверен, что это у меня какая-то ошибка в настройках. Если вы мне предложите меня код, я откажусь. Если предложите поменять настройки, то буду благодарен.

Comment: никто не предлагает вам на текущий момент менять код, просто без кода сложно понять что может быть причиной такого поведения, согласитесь что  если все-таки код потребует правок, то придется править, чтобы все работало везде как нужно?

Comment: Я не знаю, где находится код, выводящий Категории товара по указанному шорткоду.